# Connecting 2 images in android

Tags: android

I want to connect 2 images in android. Example,

[image]

[image]

I want them to be like this,
[image]

I have already done it by hard coding. First I find the upper left of the green image and then find the the most lower left point of the green side.I do it with touch event's event.gerRawX() and event.getRawY() parameters. Now I know the distance in x and y between those two points. I do the similar thing for the red one too. Now when green piece is moved close to the red I just calculate if upper left point of red piece is near to the lower left of the green piece. if so I translate the green one/ red one to the other one. But this hard coded calculation should fail for same size tablet or phone with different resolution. I just want to know how do I generalize the solution. Thanks.

Edit: My GameActivity and ImageInfo class where I try to connect both images. I have actually 6 images like this. And i wanto connect them. Like image 1 will connect to image 2 and image 2 to 3 and so on.

GameActivity class

```
package com.example.JigSawPuzzle;


import com.example.test.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;    
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
static double screenInches;
int touchStartX = 0;
int touchStartY = 0;

int diffX = 0;
int diffY = 0;
int attachedPieces=0;
int imageX = 0;
int imageY = 0;
int height,width;
boolean [] flag = new boolean[7];
boolean isPortait;
RelativeLayout relataivelayoutLayout;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsA,paramsB,paramsC,paramsD,paramsE,paramsF;
ImageView imageA,imageB,imageC,imageD,imageE,imageF;
ImageInfo [] imageInfoArray = new ImageInfo[7];

// added for sound effect
private SoundPool soundPool;
private int correctPieceAttachSoundId,gameFinishSoundId;
private boolean loaded = false;

//for 10inch landscape height = 752, width = 1280; portrait height = 1232 width = 800

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isPortait = (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) ?  false : true;
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    height = display.getHeight();
    width = display.getWidth();     

    imageA = new ImageView(this);
    imageB = new ImageView(this);
    imageC = new ImageView(this);
    imageD = new ImageView(this);
    imageE = new ImageView(this);
    imageF = new ImageView(this);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
    double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
    screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);


    if(screenInches>9.0)
    {

        imageA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a); 
        imageB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);
        imageC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.c);
        imageD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.d);
        imageE.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.e);
        imageF.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f);
    }
    else
    {
        imageA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aa);    
        imageB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bb);
        imageC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cc);
        imageD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dd);
        imageE.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ee);
        imageF.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ff);
    }



    imageA.setId(1);
    imageA.setTag("a");
    paramsA = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //The WRAP_CONTENT parameters can be replaced by an absolute width and height or the FILL_PARENT option)                
    imageA.setLayoutParams(paramsA);
    imageA.setOnTouchListener(this);
    //Log.d("GameActivity", "")



    imageB.setId(2);
    imageB.setTag("b");
    paramsB = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //The WRAP_CONTENT parameters can be replaced by an absolute width and height or the FILL_PARENT option)
    imageB.setLayoutParams(paramsB);
    imageB.setOnTouchListener(this);



    imageC.setId(3);
    imageC.setTag("c");
    paramsC = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //The WRAP_CONTENT parameters can be replaced by an absolute width and height or the FILL_PARENT option)
    imageC.setLayoutParams(paramsC);
    imageC.setOnTouchListener(this);


    imageD.setId(4);
    imageD.setTag("d");
    paramsD = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //The WRAP_CONTENT parameters can be replaced by an absolute width and height or the FILL_PARENT option)
    imageD.setLayoutParams(paramsD);
    imageD.setOnTouchListener(this);


    imageE.setId(5);
    imageE.setTag("e");
    paramsE = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //The WRAP_CONTENT parameters can be replaced by an absolute width and height or the FILL_PARENT option)
    imageE.setLayoutParams(paramsE);
    imageE.setOnTouchListener(this);

    imageF.setId(6);
    imageF.setTag("f");
    paramsF = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //The WRAP_CONTENT parameters can be replaced by an absolute width and height or the FILL_PARENT option)
    imageF.setLayoutParams(paramsF);
    imageF.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setupPieces();


    // Set the hardware buttons to control the music
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // Load the sound
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {

            loaded = true;
        }
    });

    gameFinishSoundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.bells, 1);
    correctPieceAttachSoundId= soundPool.load(this, R.raw.bell, 1);

}

public void playSound(int soundId)
{
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
    // Is the sound loaded already?
    if (loaded) 
    {
        soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1.0f);
    }
}

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
    {
//        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
//        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 //   Toast.makeText(this, "in OnConfiguaration Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    isPortait = (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) ?  false : true;
    ((RelativeLayout)imageA.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    Log.d("GameActivity", "in onconfigurationChanged");
    setupPieces();
}
public void setupPieces()
{
    RelativeLayout relataivelayoutLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    height = display.getHeight();
    width = display.getWidth();



    if(!isPortait)
    {
        paramsA.leftMargin = 10; //Your X coordinate
        paramsA.topMargin = 30; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    else
    {
        paramsA.leftMargin = 30; //Your X coordinate
        paramsA.topMargin = 10; //Your Y coordinate
    }


    imageA.setLayoutParams(paramsA);
    imageA.setOnTouchListener(this);
    //Log.d("GameActivity", "")


    if(!isPortait)
    {
        paramsB.leftMargin = 650; //Your X coordinate
        paramsB.topMargin = 300; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    else
    {
        paramsB.leftMargin = 300; //Your X coordinate
        paramsB.topMargin = 750; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    imageB.setLayoutParams(paramsB);
    imageB.setOnTouchListener(this);


    if(!isPortait)
    {
        paramsC.leftMargin = 400; //Your X coordinate
        paramsC.topMargin = 380; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    else
    {
        paramsC.leftMargin = 400; //Your X coordinate
        paramsC.topMargin = 350; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    imageC.setLayoutParams(paramsC);
    imageC.setOnTouchListener(this);


    if(!isPortait)
    {
        paramsD.leftMargin = 750; //Your X coordinate
        paramsD.topMargin = 20; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    else
    {
        paramsD.leftMargin = 20; //Your X coordinate
        paramsD.topMargin = 750; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    imageD.setLayoutParams(paramsD);
    imageD.setOnTouchListener(this);


    if(!isPortait)
    {
        paramsE.leftMargin = 900; //Your X coordinate
        paramsE.topMargin = 400; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    else
    {
        paramsE.leftMargin = 475; //Your X coordinate
        paramsE.topMargin = 700; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    imageE.setLayoutParams(paramsE);
    imageE.setOnTouchListener(this);


    if(!isPortait)
    {
        paramsF.leftMargin = 90; //Your X coordinate
        paramsF.topMargin = 300; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    else
    {
        paramsF.leftMargin = 90; //Your X coordinate
        paramsF.topMargin = 300; //Your Y coordinate
    }
    imageF.setLayoutParams(paramsF);
    imageF.setOnTouchListener(this);
    ImageInfo imageAinfo = new ImageInfo(imageA.getId(),imageA,1,2);
    imageInfoArray[0] = imageAinfo;
    ImageInfo imageBinfo = new ImageInfo(imageB.getId(),imageB,1,3);
    imageInfoArray[1] = imageBinfo;
    ImageInfo imageCinfo = new ImageInfo(imageC.getId(),imageC,2,4);
    imageInfoArray[2] = imageCinfo;
    ImageInfo imageDinfo = new ImageInfo(imageD.getId(),imageD,3,5);
    imageInfoArray[3] = imageDinfo;
    ImageInfo imageEinfo = new ImageInfo(imageE.getId(),imageE,4,6);
    imageInfoArray[4] = imageEinfo;
    ImageInfo imageFinfo = new ImageInfo(imageF.getId(),imageF,5,6);
    imageInfoArray[5] = imageFinfo;



    relataivelayoutLayout.addView(imageA);
    relataivelayoutLayout.addView(imageB);
    relataivelayoutLayout.addView(imageC);
    relataivelayoutLayout.addView(imageD);
    relataivelayoutLayout.addView(imageE);
    relataivelayoutLayout.addView(imageF);


    setContentView(relataivelayoutLayout);


}
private void updatePosition(int id)
{
    if(flag[imageInfoArray[id-1].id])
        return;
    flag[imageInfoArray[id-1].id] = true;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageInfoArray[id-1].imageView.getLayoutParams();
    param.leftMargin = imageInfoArray[id-1].imageView.getLeft() + diffX;
    param.topMargin  = imageInfoArray[id-1].imageView.getTop() + diffY;
    imageInfoArray[id-1].imageView.setLayoutParams(param);
    if(imageInfoArray[id-1].isTopConnected)
        updatePosition(imageInfoArray[id-1].topPieceId);
    if(imageInfoArray[id-1].isBottomConnected)
        updatePosition(imageInfoArray[id-1].bottomPieceId);
    return;
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{

    if(v instanceof ImageView)
    {

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
        ImageInfo imageInfo = imageInfoArray[imageView.getId()-1];

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
        {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                touchStartX = (int) event.getRawX();
                touchStartY = (int) event.getRawY();
                imageX = imageView.getLeft();
                imageY = imageView.getTop();
                //Toast.makeText(this, "x = "+event.getRawX()+" y = "+event.getRawY(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                touchStartX = (int) event.getRawX();
                touchStartY = (int) event.getRawY();
                imageX = imageView.getLeft();
                imageY = imageView.getTop();
                int id = imageInfo.id;
                while(imageInfo.isTopConnected)
                {
                    if(imageInfo.id == imageInfo.topPieceId)
                        break;
                    imageInfo = imageInfoArray[imageInfo.topPieceId-1];                     
                }
                if(!imageInfo.isTopConnected)
                {
                    imageView = imageInfo.imageView;
                    int topConnectingPieceId = imageInfo.topPieceId;
                    int topConnectingX=0,topConnectingY=0;
                    topConnectingX = imageInfo.calculateTopX(imageView.getLeft(), imageView.getId());
                    topConnectingY = imageInfo.calculateTopY(imageView.getTop(), imageView.getId());


                    ImageInfo topImageInfo = imageInfoArray[topConnectingPieceId-1];
                    int bottomConnectingX = topImageInfo.calculateBottomX(topImageInfo.imageView.getLeft(),topConnectingPieceId);
                    int bottomConnectingY = topImageInfo.calculateBottomY(topImageInfo.imageView.getTop(),topConnectingPieceId);
                    diffX = (bottomConnectingX-topConnectingX);
                    diffY = (bottomConnectingY-topConnectingY);
                    if(Math.abs(diffX)<=20 && Math.abs(diffY)<=20)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
                            flag[i]=false;
                        updatePosition(imageInfo.id);
                        imageInfo.setIsTopConnected(true);
                        topImageInfo.setIsBottomConnected(true);
                        attachedPieces++;
                        if(attachedPieces==5)
                        {
                            setupFinishDialogue();
                            playSound(gameFinishSoundId);
                        }
                        else
                            playSound(correctPieceAttachSoundId);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                imageInfo = imageInfoArray[id-1];
                while(imageInfo.isBottomConnected)
                {
                    if(imageInfo.id == imageInfoArray[imageInfo.bottomPieceId-1].id)
                        break;
                    imageInfo = imageInfoArray[imageInfo.bottomPieceId-1];                      
                }
                imageView = imageInfo.imageView;
                if(!imageInfo.isBottomConnected)
                {
                    int topConnectingX=0,topConnectingY=0; 
                    int bottomConnectingX = imageInfo.calculateBottomX(imageView.getLeft(), imageView.getId());
                    int bottomConnectingY = imageInfo.calculateBottomY(imageView.getTop(), imageView.getId());
                    int bottomConnectingPieceId = imageInfo.bottomPieceId;
                    ImageInfo bottomImageInfo = imageInfoArray[bottomConnectingPieceId-1];
                    topConnectingX = bottomImageInfo.calculateTopX(bottomImageInfo.imageView.getLeft(),bottomConnectingPieceId);
                    topConnectingY = bottomImageInfo.calculateTopY(bottomImageInfo.imageView.getTop(), bottomConnectingPieceId);
                    diffX = (topConnectingX-bottomConnectingX);
                    diffY = (topConnectingY-bottomConnectingY);
                    if(Math.abs(diffX)<=20 && Math.abs(diffY)<=20)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
                            flag[i]=false;
                        updatePosition(imageInfo.id);
                        imageInfo.setIsBottomConnected(true);
                        bottomImageInfo.setIsTopConnected(true);
                        attachedPieces++;
                        if(attachedPieces==5)
                        {
                            setupFinishDialogue();
                            playSound(gameFinishSoundId);
                        }
                        else
                            playSound(correctPieceAttachSoundId);
                    }
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                diffX = (int) (event.getRawX() - touchStartX);
                diffY = (int) (event.getRawY() - touchStartY);
                touchStartX = (int)event.getRawX();
                touchStartY = (int)event.getRawY();

                for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
                    flag[i]=false;                  
                updatePosition(imageInfo.id);       
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    return true;
}

void lockOrientation()
{
    switch (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation)
    {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
            {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
            else 
            {
                int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                if(rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_90|| rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_180)
                {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
                }
                else 
                {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }
            }   
            break;

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
            {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
            else 
            {
                int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                if(rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_90){
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

void setupFinishDialogue()
{
    /*if(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()==3)
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    else if(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()==1)
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
    else if(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()==2)
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
    else setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);*/


    lockOrientation();

    AlertDialog.Builder builderForAlertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builderForAlertBox.setCancelable(false).setMessage("Good Job!").setPositiveButton("Restart", dialogClickListner).setNegativeButton("Quit", dialogClickListner).
    setCancelable(true).show(); 
}
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListner = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{       
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        switch (which) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GameActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            finish();
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
};
```

}

ImageInfo Class

```
package com.example.JigSawPuzzle;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageInfo 
{
ImageView imageView;
int imageATopLeftDifferenceX = -1;
int imageATopLeftDifferenceY = -1;
int imageABottomRightDifferenceX = 113;
int imageABottomRightDifferenceY = 140;

int imageBTopLeftDifferenceX = 0;
int imageBTopLeftDifferenceY = 0;
int imageBBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
int imageBBottomRightDifferenceY = 111;

int imageCTopLeftDifferenceX = 14;
int imageCTopLeftDifferenceY = 0;
int imageCBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
int imageCBottomRightDifferenceY = 88;

int imageDTopLeftDifferenceX = 92;
int imageDTopLeftDifferenceY = 2;
int imageDBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
int imageDBottomRightDifferenceY = 70;

/*int imageETopLeftDifferenceX = 0;
int imageETopLeftDifferenceY = 0;
int imageEBottomRightDifferenceX = 55;
int imageEBottomRightDifferenceY = 112;*/
int imageETopLeftDifferenceX = 55;
int imageETopLeftDifferenceY = 112;
int imageEBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
int imageEBottomRightDifferenceY = 0;

/*int imageFTopLeftDifferenceX = 0;
int imageFTopLeftDifferenceY = 26;
int imageFBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
int imageFBottomRightDifferenceY = 109;
int id,topPieceId,bottomPieceId;*/
int imageFTopLeftDifferenceX = 0;
int imageFTopLeftDifferenceY = 109;
int imageFBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
int imageFBottomRightDifferenceY = 26;
int id,topPieceId,bottomPieceId;

boolean isTopConnected = false;
boolean isBottomConnected = false;
public ImageInfo(int id,ImageView imageView,int topPieceId,int bottomPieceId)
{
    this.topPieceId = topPieceId;
    this.bottomPieceId = bottomPieceId;
    this.imageView = imageView;
    this.id = id;
    if(id==1)
        isTopConnected = true;
    else if(id==6)
        isBottomConnected = true;
    if(GameActivity.screenInches>9.0)
        initializePiecesInfo();
}
private void initializePiecesInfo() 
{

    imageATopLeftDifferenceX = 0;
    imageATopLeftDifferenceY = 0;
    imageABottomRightDifferenceX = 150;
    imageABottomRightDifferenceY = 184;

    imageBTopLeftDifferenceX = 0;
    imageBTopLeftDifferenceY = 0;
    imageBBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
    imageBBottomRightDifferenceY = 148;

    imageCTopLeftDifferenceX = 23;
    imageCTopLeftDifferenceY = 0;
    imageCBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
    imageCBottomRightDifferenceY = 115;

    imageDTopLeftDifferenceX = 121;
    imageDTopLeftDifferenceY = 0;
    imageDBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
    imageDBottomRightDifferenceY = 91;

    /*int imageETopLeftDifferenceX = 0;
    int imageETopLeftDifferenceY = 0;
    int imageEBottomRightDifferenceX = 55;
    int imageEBottomRightDifferenceY = 112;*/
    imageETopLeftDifferenceX = 74;
    imageETopLeftDifferenceY = 147;
    imageEBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
    imageEBottomRightDifferenceY = 0;

    /*int imageFTopLeftDifferenceX = 0;
    int imageFTopLeftDifferenceY = 26;
    int imageFBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
    int imageFBottomRightDifferenceY = 109;
    int id,topPieceId,bottomPieceId;*/
    imageFTopLeftDifferenceX = 0;
    imageFTopLeftDifferenceY = 144;
    imageFBottomRightDifferenceX = 0;
    imageFBottomRightDifferenceY = 26;
}

int calculateTopX(int realX,int id)
{
    if(id==2)
        return realX+imageBTopLeftDifferenceX;
    if(id==3)
        return realX+imageCTopLeftDifferenceX;
    if(id==4)
        return realX+imageDTopLeftDifferenceX;
    if(id==5)
        return realX+imageETopLeftDifferenceX;
    if(id==6)
        return realX+imageFTopLeftDifferenceX;
    return realX;

}
int calculateTopY(int realY,int id)
{
    if(id==2)
        return realY+imageBTopLeftDifferenceY;
    if(id==3)
        return realY+imageCTopLeftDifferenceY;
    if(id==4)
        return realY+imageDTopLeftDifferenceY;
    if(id==5)
        return realY+imageETopLeftDifferenceY;
    if(id==6)
        return realY+imageFTopLeftDifferenceY;
    return realY;
}

int calculateBottomX(int realX,int id)
{
    if(id==1)
        return realX+imageABottomRightDifferenceX;
    if(id==2)
        return realX+imageBBottomRightDifferenceX;
    if(id==3)
        return realX+imageCBottomRightDifferenceX;
    if(id==4)
        return realX+imageDBottomRightDifferenceX;
    if(id==5)
        return realX+imageEBottomRightDifferenceX;
    return realX+imageFBottomRightDifferenceX;      
}
int calculateBottomY(int realY,int id)
{
    if(id==1)
        return realY+imageABottomRightDifferenceY;
    if(id==2)
        return realY+imageBBottomRightDifferenceY;
    if(id==3)
        return realY+imageCBottomRightDifferenceY;
    if(id==4)
        return realY+imageDBottomRightDifferenceY;
    if(id==5)
        return realY+imageEBottomRightDifferenceY;
    return realY+imageFBottomRightDifferenceY;
}
void setIsTopConnected(boolean isTopConnected)
{
    this.isTopConnected = isTopConnected;
}
void setIsBottomConnected(boolean isBottomConnected)
{
    this.isBottomConnected = isBottomConnected;
}

}
```

Comment: I think you can't implement it exact....images may override you may miss line between red and green

Comment: But there must be some solution right? I now only check if its a 7 inch tab or 10 inch tab. Should I also check for if a 7/10inch tab and also different resolutions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Given the images you provided it is straightforward to connect them in a generic way because the images have the same width and they have transparent background, here is the idea:

1- You need the overlap distance between the two images, which you can calculate from either the bottom or top image

[image]

The green line in the bottom picture should be equal to the red line in the top picture

[image: bottom image]

Given that your images have transparent background you can calculate this distance easily, I will use the bottom image here.

The idea is to check every pixel in the last column of the bottom bitmap (i.e. width - 1) and stop once you hit a non-transparent pixel.

```
 private int getOverlapDistance(Bitmap bottomBitmap) {
    int height = bottomBitmap.getHeight();
    int width = bottomBitmap.getWidth();
    int distance = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        if (Color.alpha(bottomBitmap.getPixel(width - 1, i)) != 0) {
            distance = (i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return distance;
}
```

To connect them you can do something like (assuming you have separate `ImageView` for the top and bottom image):

```
bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) bottomImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int overlapDistance = getOverlapDistance(bitmap);
bottomImage.setTop(topImage.getBottom() - overlapDistance);
```

Actually I tried this with a simple activity and it is working, here is how it look like before and after connecting the two images:

[image: Images before connecting]

I just execute the above code when the button `connect` is clicked

[image: After connecting]